# Using Jsoup to connect to url, but Jsoup call another url. Why?

Tags: java, url, jsoup

I tried to use Jsoup to crawl this

```
Document dok = Jsoup.connect("http://bola.kompas.com/ligaindonesia").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").timeout(0).get();
```

but error appeared like this:

```
java.io.IOException: Too many redirects occurred trying to load URL http://m.kompas.com/bola
```

And, when I type this:

```
Document dok = Jsoup.connect("http://m.kompas.com/bola").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").timeout(0).get();
```

error appeared like this:

```
java.io.IOException: Too many redirects occurred trying to load URL http://bola.kompas.com
```

Actually this is my full code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.HttpStatusException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class MainBackup {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        processCrawling_kompas("http://bola.kompas.com/ligaindonesia");
    }

    public static void processCrawling_kompas(String URL){
        try{
            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(URL).timeout(0).execute();
            int statusCode = response.statusCode();
            if(statusCode == 200){
                Document dok = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").timeout(0).get();
                System.out.println("opened page: "+ URL);

                Elements nextPages = dok.select("a");
                for(Element nextPage: nextPages){
                    if(nextPage != null){
                        if(nextPage.attr("href").contains("bola.kompas.com")){
                            processCrawling_kompas(nextPage.attr("abs:href"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (HttpStatusException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What exactly happened in here? How to solve this?

Thanks for your help before :)

Comment: Try `.followRedirects(true)`.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your issue with the exact same code, you need to provide us with more information.

Comment: I've added the full code in the post, sorry.. @JoelMin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea to provide a userAgent is the right idea. If you do this also in the first call of Jsoup, it will work as expected.

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(URL)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
            .timeout(0).execute();
```

By the way - the response object already contains the full html, so you do not need to call connect again to get to the document. Try this:

```
String URL = "http://bola.kompas.com/ligaindonesia";
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(URL)
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
        .timeout(0).execute();
int statusCode = response.statusCode();
if(statusCode == 200){
    Document dok = Jsoup.parse(response.body(),URL);
    System.out.println("opened page: "+ URL);

    //your stuff

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the first line of your `processCrawling_kompas` to this:

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").timeout(0).execute();
```

The change is to add user agent! With this code I was able to get the following output:

```
opened page: https://login.kompas.com/act.php?do=ForgotPasswd&skin=default&sr=mykompas&done=http....
```